# Exclude current post from the output

Tags: php, wordpress, post, widget

I have written a Wordpress widget that displays a custom amount of posts from a custom tag (feel free to use it). Here is the code:

```
    <?php 
    $category = get_the_category();
    $current_category = $category[0]->term_id;
    ?>

    <?php query_posts("showposts=".$posts_number."&cat=".$current_category."&tag=featured"); // the tag
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="block-post clearfix">
            <?php
                $thumb = '';
                $width = 287;
                $height = 162;
                $classtext = 'post-image';
                $titletext = get_the_title();
                $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'Recent');
                $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
            ?>

            <?php if($thumb <> '' && get_option('aggregate_thumbnails_index') == 'on') { ?>
                <div class="thumb">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
                        <span class="overlaybig"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>  <!-- end .post-thumbnail -->
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="recenttitle"><h3 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>
        </div> <!-- end .block-post -->
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

My question is, how can I exclude the current post from the output? The problem is that it does not check if the user is currently viewing any of the posts that it outputs. **How can I adjust the code so that it skips the current post that the user is on**?

I am pretty sure that this is an easy fix, but I am lost at the moment.

**UPDATE:** Here is the code for the entire widget, including the fix provided by maiorano84:

```
<?php class ArtificePinned extends WP_Widget
{
    function ArtificePinned(){
        $widget_ops = array('description' => 'Displays posts filtered by current category and the tag pinned');
        $control_ops = array('width' => 400, 'height' => 300);
        parent::WP_Widget(false,$name='Artifice Pinned',$widget_ops,$control_ops);
    }

  /* Displays the Widget in the front-end */
    function widget($args, $instance){
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? ' ' : $instance['title']);
        $posts_number = empty($instance['posts_number']) ? '' : (int) $instance['posts_number'];

        echo $before_widget;

        if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
?>

<?php 
$category = get_the_category();
$current_category = $category[0]->term_id;
$qarr = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_number,
    'cat' => $current_category,
    'tag' => 'featured',
    'post__not_in' => get_the_ID()
);
$q = new WP_Query($qarr);
if($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
?>
    <div class="block-post clearfix">
        <?php
            $thumb = '';
            $width = 287;
            $height = 162;
            $classtext = 'post-image';
            $titletext = get_the_title();
            $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'Recent');
            $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
        ?>

        <?php if($thumb <> '' && get_option('aggregate_thumbnails_index') == 'on') { ?>
            <div class="thumb">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
                    <span class="overlaybig"></span>
                </a>
            </div>  <!-- end .post-thumbnail -->
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="recenttitle"><h3 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>
    </div> <!-- end .block-post -->
<?php endwhile; endif;?>

<?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

  /*Saves the settings. */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = stripslashes($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['posts_number'] = (int) $new_instance['posts_number'];

        return $instance;
    }

  /*Creates the form for the widget in the back-end. */
    function form($instance){
        //Defaults
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array('title'=>' ', 'posts_number'=>'7') );

        $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
        $posts_number = (int) $instance['posts_number'];

        # Title
        echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '">' . 'Title:' . '</label><input class="widefat" id="' . $this->get_field_id('title') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('title') . '" type="text" value="' . $title . '" /></p>';
        # Number Of Posts
        echo '<p><label for="' . $this->get_field_id('posts_number') . '">' . 'Number of Posts:' . '</label><input class="widefat" id="' . $this->get_field_id('posts_number') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('posts_number') . '" type="text" value="' . $posts_number . '" /></p>';
        # Category ?>

        <?php
    }

}// end ArtificePinned class

function ArtificePinnedInit() {
  register_widget('ArtificePinned');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'ArtificePinnedInit');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use query_posts, as its intention is to modify the default Wordpress Loop. Use [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead.

To answer your question, the solution is pretty simple. I've taken the liberty of giving you this example using WP_Query:

```
<?php
$qarr = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_number,
    'cat' => $current_category,
    'tag' => 'featured',
    'post__not_in' => get_the_ID()
);
$q = new WP_Query($qarr);
if($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
?>
```

Bear in mind, I've also changed 'showposts' to 'posts_per_page', as showposts was deprecated in version 2.1

**UPDATE**: Your code should now look like this:

```
<?php 
$category = get_the_category();
$current_category = $category[0]->term_id;
$qarr = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_number,
    'cat' => $current_category,
    'tag' => 'featured',
    'post__not_in' => get_the_ID()
);
$q = new WP_Query($qarr);
if($q->have_posts()) : while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
?>
    <div class="block-post clearfix">
        <?php
            $thumb = '';
            $width = 287;
            $height = 162;
            $classtext = 'post-image';
            $titletext = get_the_title();
            $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,$classtext,$titletext,$titletext,false,'Recent');
            $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
        ?>

        <?php if($thumb <> '' && get_option('aggregate_thumbnails_index') == 'on') { ?>
            <div class="thumb">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, $classtext); ?>
                    <span class="overlaybig"></span>
                </a>
            </div>  <!-- end .post-thumbnail -->
        <?php } ?>

        <div class="recenttitle"><h3 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3></div>
    </div> <!-- end .block-post -->
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
```

**FIX:**

The problem is stemming from this:

```
'post__not_in' => get_the_ID()
```

The problem is 'post__not_in' expects an array. Not an integer. My apologies, that was my mistake. Please change that line of code to:

```
'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID())
```

and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although I just tested your code, it gave me two errors: **array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array** and **implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in**. Do you know what the issue is and how we resolve it?

Comment: Yes it does, both errors are on line: **public_html/delheat/wordpress/wp-includes/query.php on line 2162**

Comment: Please review my update, and make sure your page looks how I've described. For redundancy's sake, copy and paste the whole block of code into place.

Comment: I added your code but the same 2 errors returned. There must be some issue somewhere. I have updated my question with the whole script for the widget with your code included, maybe something else in the script is interfering with its functionalities? Can you kindly have a look?

Comment: I've copied and pasted your block on my end, and I've replicated the error. Give me a moment.

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly now! Thank you dearly. I have a remaining question, why should I not use query_posts and use WP Query as you suggested? I did not understand your explanation of it. I am asking this because I am using query_posts in different parts of my site so should I change them all?...

Comment: It would be best if you did. There IS a time and a place for it, but 90% of the time, it's used incorrectly. [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts) should clarify things a bit for you. Good luck.

Comment: Update: Sorry to bother you with this issue, but it appears that posts_per_page does not function at all? Do you by any chance have any idea why?